# Not able to retrieve object properties when looping through objects in indexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I am not able to retrieve properties when looping through objects stored in indexedDB. When i attempt to get objects trough `tasksStore.get(i);`, i get the error `Cannot read property 'property' of undefined at IDBRequest.getTasks.onsuccess`, however, if I change it to `tasksStore.get(1);`, it works fine, and gets object with id=1 x index's length.

I've tried checking the typeof of both ways, and they both return number.

```
//success handler on connection
    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        db = request.result;

        //define store index
        tasksStore = tasksTx.objectStore("tasksStore");

        //error handler on result of the request
        db.onerror = function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR " + e.target.errorCode);
        }

        //variable for counting objects in the index
        let amountOfTasks = tasksIndex.count();

        //error handler
        amountOfTasks.onerror = function() {
            console.log("There was an error finding the amount of tasks")
        }

        //success handler
        amountOfTasks.onsuccess = function() {
            for (var i = 1; i < amountOfTasks.result; i++) {
                let getTasks = tasksStore.get(i);

                let getTasksElementContainer = document.getElementById("list-tasks");
                let createTasksList = document.createElement("li");
                createTasksList.id = "task-" + i;

                getTasks.onerror = function() {
                    console.log("There was an error looping through the tasks")
                }

                getTasks.onsuccess = function() {
                    console.log(getTasks.result.title); //getTasks.result works, getTasks.result.title does not.
                    getTasksElementContainer.appendChild(createTasksList);
                    //JSON stringify to return object in string format, and not [Object object]
                    createTasksList.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(getTasks.result.title);
                }
            }   
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `IDBObjectStore.get` with a key that doesn't exist in your database, the resulting value is undefined. That likely explains why sometimes `getTasks.result` is undefined.

If you're still having trouble, you'd likely be well served by making a self-contained reproducible example. You'll probably find your own bug in the process of doing that. If not, it's easier to get more specific help on Stack Overflow if you have some code that other people can run to directly observe the problem (so including database creation and inserting data).